# How to emit a Tauri window event from rocket request

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, tauri

I hope this is not too obscure.

I am playing around with Tauri where I want to expose a web based control panel for the app.
By going to a url on the local network, eg http://192.168.1.101:8000/some-action, it will send a window message to the Tauri app running on that machine. Imagine a dashboard app in an office where users on the network can control how the app behaves via a web url.

Here is my rust code so far:

```
// use rocket runtime
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {

            let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

            #[get("/")]
            fn index() {
                // this is where I want to emit the window event if possible
                //window.emit("from-rust", format!("message")).expect("failed to emit");
            }
            
            // mount the rocket instance
            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
                let _rocket = rocket::build()
                    .mount("/", routes![index])
                    .launch().await;
                });
            
            Ok(())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

I am able to run the rocket server, however, I can't work out how to send the window event from the rocket request handler function.

Any suggestions or insights would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fn` items are not allowed to capture their environment. But since `#[get(...)]`
is only allowed to be used on `fn` you can't use it.

You can just implement the required traits for a custom struct yourself though.

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use rocket::http::Method;
use rocket::route::{Handler, Outcome};
use rocket::{Data, Request, Route};
use tauri::{Manager, generate_context};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct WindowHandler {
    window: tauri::Window,
}

impl WindowHandler {
    fn new(window: tauri::Window) -> Self {
        Self { window }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl Handler for WindowHandler {
    async fn handle<'r>(&self, request: &'r Request<'_>, data: Data<'r>) -> Outcome<'r> {
        self.window
            .emit("from-rust", format!("message"))
            .expect("failed to emit");
        todo!()
    }
}
impl From<WindowHandler> for Vec<Route> {
    fn from(value: WindowHandler) -> Self {
        vec![Route::new(Method::Get, "/", value)]
    }
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

            let index = WindowHandler::new(window);
            // mount the rocket instance
            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
                let _rocket = rocket::build().mount("/", index).launch().await;
            });
            Ok(())
        })
        .run(generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

---

Or another possibility is to use a global `WINDOW: OnceLock<Window>` like this:

```rust
#![feature(once_cell)]
use std::sync::OnceLock;

use rocket::{get, routes};
use tauri::{Manager, generate_context, Window};

static WINDOW: OnceLock<Window> = OnceLock::new();
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

            _ = WINDOW.set(window);

            #[get("/")]
            fn index() {
                WINDOW.get().expect("window is available").emit("from-rust", format!("message")).expect("failed to emit");
            }
            // mount the rocket instance
            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
                let _rocket = rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index]).launch().await;
            });
            Ok(())
        })
        .run(generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. The rocket::handler Trait worked a treat. I got a panic on outcome `todo!()`. So I changed it to `Outcome::from(request, "success")` and it all worked perfectly. The second option failed for me only because `#![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel.`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to use your first example, but because my setup function does more with `window` I'm bumping into a `use of moved value 'window'` error. I've tried turning it into a borrow but then I get into lifetime hell. I'm really new to rust and haven't got a clear grasp of lifetime annotations yet, so I'm constantly bumping into compiler errors with what seem like conflicting recommendations about how to fix my code. Any guidance you can provide will be super helpful

Comment: Ah! So I found it's possible to call `app.get_window("main").unwrap()` multiple times to get multiple references to a window, so I simply referred to a second call to it as a different variable name: `let http_window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();` and used `http_window` instead of `window` in my rocket instantiation... so I'm now up and running!